# Can't debug with Xdebug 2.7 and PHP 7.0 on my new Apple M2?

Tags: bash, macos, xdebug, macos-monterey

I've installed php8 with brew and then I discovered that the needed version should be 7.0 due to a legacy code. I've installed php7.

```bash
PHP 7.0.33 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2022 12:20:53) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

But now I need Xdebug. I've verified the matrix of [Xdebug/PHP](https://xdebug.org/docs/compat#versions) versions and because my PHP version 7.0 I can work with Xdebug from version 2.4 to version 2.7.

I decided to check GitHub website and [download version 2.7.2](https://%20https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/releases/tag/2.7.2) of Xdebug. Then I followed instructions in [this link](https://%20https://profilingviewer.com/installing-xdebug-on-high-sierra.html):

```
tar xzf xdebug-2.7.2.tgz
cd xdebug-2.7.2
phpize
```

but the result is a good

```bash
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20220829
Zend Module Api No:      20220829
Zend Extension Api No:   420220829
```

followed by a very bad

```bash
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/php.m4: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/shtool: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/libtool.m4: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/ax_check_compile_flag.m4: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/ax_gcc_func_attribute.m4: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/php_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/pkg.m4: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/config.guess: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/config.sub: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/ltmain.sh: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/Makefile.global: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/build/gen_stub.php: Permission denied
cp: /Users/simonegentili/Development/xdebug-2.7.2/run-tests.php: Permission denied
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_C' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:72: AC_LANG_C is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_C' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:72: AC_LANG_C is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:561: _LT_AC_LOCK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:561: _LT_AC_LOCK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2739: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2738: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not exist
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not exist
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not look like a libtool script
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not look like a libtool script
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: using \`LTCC=$LTCC', extracted from \`$ofile'
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: using \`LTCC=$LTCC', extracted from \`$ofile'
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: tag name \"$tagname\" already exists
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:262: AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2821: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2820: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2821: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2820: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1185: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2821: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2820: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1929: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.0 and Xdebug 2.7 are no longer supported. Please use supported versions of software.

Comment: "Please use supported versions of software." I cant, now. This is not the solution now. But thank you for the answer.